Does delete SQL query work with CTE or WITH clause in couchbase?
Does delete SQL query work with a CTE or WITH clause in couchbase?
I get this error :

Syntax error at: DELETE (reserved word)

My code:
WITH inactiveDocs AS 
(
    SELECT META(d).id
    FROM example_bucket d
    WHERE d.status = "inactive"
)
DELETE FROM example_bucket d
WHERE META(d).id IN (SELECT RAW id FROM inactiveDocs);


Is there a reason you want to use a CTE and not a (inner) join?


Does delete SQL query work with a CTE or WITH clause in couchbase?

Couchbase does not support the use of WITH statements in any context other than SELECT statements; this is delineated very clearly in their documentation for WITH:

The WITH clause can only be used preceding a SELECT statement [...]

Notably, this differs from some of Couchbase's more traditional RDBMS counterparts like SQL Server/T-SQL, MySQL, and PostgreSQL, just to name a few.
